# MYSQL query or procedure to retrieve down line team list quickly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, query-optimization

I have tried few queries but it is working for small data, need some optimized query or procedure to process large data.

Consider following tables:

user_team:

```
sno     user_id     placed_under     position
 1        100          root             -
 2        101          100              A
 3        102          100              B
 4        103          101              A
 5        104          102              B
 6        105          101              B
 7        106          102              A
 8        107          104              A
 9        108          105              B
 10       109          108              A
```

user_product:

```
sno     user_id     product_id
 1        100          p123
 2        101          p125
 3        102          p123
 4        103          p124
 5        105          p125
 6        106          p127
 7        109          p124
```

user_team is a tree data i.e, 100 is root and rest are his/her team.

problem:

Finding a user's team products list.

exmaple:
finding the 101's team and their product_id.
since 103 and 105 are placed under 101 they are 101's children and as 108 is placed under 105 and 109 is placed under 108, 108 and 109 belongs to 101 team.
So, 101 team contains 103, 105, 108 and 109. Now it should search for product_id from user_product.

output: (108 is not shown because there is no product assigned)

```
user_id  product_id
  103       p124
  105       p125
  109       p124
```

I want a query which would find the team product details

Comment: `I want a query which would find the team product details` upwork.com is what you're looking for your **demand**.

Comment: At least show us your own best attempt, perhaps we can then easily see how that can be improved. I do wonder whoever can up with this 'recursive' data scheme, you really need that?